# How to boot to nvme and install grub to external drive?

Tags: boot, grub2, nvme

I have one SSD and two NVME.

My old motherboard does not detect the NVME to boot it.

I tried to install the system and the boot in the NVME, but it was not detected by CLOVER (https://github.com/CloverHackyColor/CloverBootloader).

I tried to install the system in the NVME and boot on USB Stick, but the GRUB accuses the "Unkown Filesystem".

I tried to open the GRUB via the command line and when typing "blkid" or "ls -l", NVME is not detected.

How can I install the boot on an external disk but load the system inside the NVME ?

Comment: The installer has a bug, launchpad bug #1396379, which prevents installing grub where you specify, but you can install grub directly after the install where you want it (from the "try" option).

Comment: I can't boot to nvme without the external boot. I need to install grub to an external drive before the first time boot.

Comment: If UEFI/BIOS does not see hardware, then operating system cannot use it. This sounds like an old BIOS system, so how did you install NVMe drives. Any newer motherboard with m.2 and NVMe will support it in UEFI boot. If system that old, then SSD would be better anyway as extra speed from NVMe will not really be used. But I am finding the slowest part of my system is PEBCAK stands for Problem Exists Between Chair and Keyboard. And over time it gets slower. :(

Comment: I know and I've already said that.

Comment: To be clearer, boot the install media in "try" mode, run grub-install to another USB which you want to use to boot the NVME. See man grub-install for some options which may be necessary. Running grub-install directly will work, unlike when trying from the normal install process..